# alternative layout when using Graphviz and Quickgraph

Tags: c#, graphviz, quickgraph

I have converted the example available at this page to a windows application one.
http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/How-to-render-a-finite-state-machine-graph-in-ASPNET-.aspx

The application is generating the images as expected but when i try to change the layout, I am not able to get it to work . I am trying to use "Circo" or "Sfdp" instead of the "dot". I have tried the following changes but the generated image always has the exact layout as the "dot" one:

1- I changed the line:

`process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.21\bin\dot.exe";`

to:
`process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.21\bin\sfdp.exe";`

or:
`process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.21\bin\circo.exe";`

2- I added " -Kspfg"/" -Kcirco" to
`process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Tgif -Gcharset=latin1";`

3- I tried combining 1 and 2

none of the above seems to work. could you please help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

fixed.. there was problem with arguments spaces in my code.

Thanks thu,